# Librería o componente para hacer gráficos estadísticos en C++

Tags: c++, macos

Estoy trabajando con unos algoritmos donde requiero desplegar el rendimiento (en tiempo) de cada uno de ellos.

He estado buscando librerías para poder hacer gráficos, pero realmente o soy malo buscando o no las encuentro. Sé que una opción podría ser **Qt**, pero actualmente tenemos una red muy limitada y me tardaría eternidades en descargar **Qt** para hacer las gráficas.

¿Hay alguna librería que sea **cross-platform** con la cual pueda construir gráficos en C++, o que la pueda usar en **OS X**?

Answer (score 2):

Hola una manera (muy utilizada) es pasar mediante el comando `pipe` de UNIX la salida de tu programa a un txt y de alli llamar a GNU plot. Por ejemplo yo he generado unos datos con un programa C++ y los guardo en un `.txt`:

`./my_cpp_program > datos.txt`

```
2 2 1.41421 1
3 2 1.41421 1
4 2.66667 1.49071 1
5 3 1.58114 1
6 3.6 1.67332 1
7 4 1.76383 1
8 4.57143 1.85164 1
9 5 1.93649 1
10 5.55556 2.01843 1
11 6 2.09762 1
12 6.54545 2.17423 1
13 7 2.24846 1
14 7.53846 2.32048 1
15 8 2.39046 1
```

luego tengo un archivo de configuracion(gnuplot_setup):

```
set style data lines
set offsets 0,0,0,0
set yrange [0:9]
set samples 100

plot "datos.txt" u 1:2 title "mis datos1" smooth cspline, '' u 1:3 title "mis datos2" smooth cspline, '' u 1:4 title "prueba GNU Plot" smooth cspline
```

y por ultimo un desde consola: `gnuplot -p gnuplot_setup`

Se puede automatizar todo el proceso en un script de bash
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aunque no contesta la pregunta directamente, es una buena solución que desacopla la generación del gráfico de la generación de los datos. buen trabajo.

Answer (score 1):

Con una sencilla [búsqueda en Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=chart+c%2B%2B+library) he podido averiguar que [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) es bastante popular y multiplataforma.

Otros candidatos a tener en cuenta:

- [dislin](http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin).
- [wxMathPlot](http://wxmathplot.sourceforge.net/).
- [koolplot](http://koolplot.codecutter.org/).
- [plotutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/).
- [plplot](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: ¿Si sabes que gnuplot necesita un API de 3eros para ser integrado en el **código de C++**? Por eso no lo usé, ando buscando alguna librería o componente que me **permita trabajar gráficos con C++**, de nada me sirve usar gnuplot si no se puede integrar a mi código. Gracias por las demás sugerencias, los checaré.

Comment: @ArturoG. por lo que veo de gnuplot, [su descarga](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2055) ya incluye todo lo necesario para empezar a trabajar con él.